# Strange chord notations in piano sheet: Twisted by Annie Ross

Tags: jazz, blues

I have to play Twisted with a jazz singer and I came found this lead sheet where the chords are written strangely. Is this the standard notation? Eg., is B'6 = Bbmaj7?
Does anyone know where I can get better B major notes? I found the sheet music here: https://pdfcoffee.com/twisted-lead-sheet-annie-ross-1-pdf-free.html.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this sort of thing before - the font used to display the guitar chord symbols doesn't contain the musical flat symbol, and defaulted to apostrophe instead.

The key signature (on the five line musical stave) contains two flats, so that first chord is definitely a B flat chord, not a B natural chord. The tune contains the two notes A flat and F, so the accompanying chord is B flat 7.

[image]

Comment: Yes, a misprint,  probably a font issue. Heck, DEFINITELY a font issue. End of.

Answer (score 2):

Since the piece is written in B♭, it's safe to assume the commas (or no.6) is a misprint, and the chords called B'7 will in fact be B♭7 in reality. Same would go for the E' - should be E♭. B♭maj7 could also have been written with a triangle - B♭▵.

Comment: The 6’s are actually sixth chords, I confirmed that with the Sher version in The New Real Book. Also Sher uses “ma” and “mi” in chord symbols for major and minor respectively, something I don’t care for because they are small and can be hard to tell apart at a glance. Apart from that the Sher books are very good and accurate.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - I'd have expected the 6ths to be maj6. With you on 'ma' and 'mi', also using '-' for minors. No real need for *anything* on majors, surely.

Comment: In my experience 6th chords are not preceded by “maj”, just: C6 or F#6 for example.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - exactly. Can't remember ever seeing them labelled any other way. I put 'maj' in for clarity! C6, F#6 are just as I would expect. Min 6, though, would be Cm6, F#m6 etc. Agreed?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - aahh - I meant that the comma/apostrophe looked like an upside down 6, (or even a badly printed 9) not referring to the 6th chord.

Comment: Oh, that explains it!